# lagrange multiplier determinant

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Can someone please explain why in my textbook they write lagrange multiplier like this :
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\
\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$
I don't understand where did this determinant come from and why is this determinant equal to zero? I just know that the lagrange multiplier is : $f_x(x_0,y_0)=\lambda g_x(x_0,y_0),f_y(x_0,y_0)=\lambda g_y(x_0,y_0)$

Comment: Which problem is the textbook trying to solve with Lagrange multipliers? Edit it into your question. (Presumably, we have a constraint for which $f-\lambda g$ depends on neither $x$ nor $y$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f_i=\lambda g_i\implies f_xg_y=\lambda g_xg_y=g_xf_y$, so the determinant is $f_xg_y-g_xf_y=0$.